# Linq Statement Difference.

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

could someone explain the difference. I am trying to avoid the hidden files in a folder and get the count. The 1 statement does not work but the second
 statement works. I am unable to to figure out why. And What is the use of '&' in linq. thanks in Advance!

```
subFolder.GetFiles().Select(Function(k) k).Where(Function(m) m.Attributes <> FileAttributes.Hidden).Count


subFolder.GetFiles().Select(Function(k) k).Where(Function(m) (m.Attributes And FileAttributes.Hidden) = 0).Count
```

Comment: In this context it is a binary (not unary) operator, so *Bitwise and*: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx

Comment: *the second statement works*?? Impossible. In VB.NET, `&` operator always means string concatenation.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens This is not C#.

Comment: @Ripple maybe option strict is off ...

Comment: @Fredou I guess so too.

Comment: @Ripple  sorry about the mess. I had to get a result Zero the second statement served my purpose but after seeing your comments, I tested it and it always returned a Zero. so I changed it to "AND". it is working for all now. Got to know a new thing posting a wrong Question :-)

Answer (score 2):

m.Attributes is a `[Flags]` enum which means each bit in the value represents a different flag.  When you do `<>` you are testing "is Hidden not the only value set?" which will be true for many files.  When you do `& == 0` you are testing "looking only at the Hidden bit, is the value set to 0?  in other words, is the Hidden flag not set?"

Answer (score 2):

`m.Attributes` can consist of a combination of some flag values, and `FileAttributes.Hidden` is one of them.(The complete list can be seen in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx))

So, the predicate of the first statement:

```
 m.Attributes <> FileAttributes.Hidden
```

tests "not (`m.Attributes` consists of only one flag `Hidden`)", that is even true for the value of the combinations of `Hidden` and `ReadOnly`, or `Hidden` and `System`, etc.

The second statement:

```
(m.Attributes And FileAttributes.Hidden) = 0
```

tests "pick up the partial value of `Hidden` from `m.Attribute`, and see if not set", that is true at least if the value doesn't have `Hidden` set, and the other flags are ignored. Hence that is false for the combinations of `Hidden` and `ReadOnly`, or `Hidden` and `System`, etc.

---

As a side note, `.Select(Function(k) k)` does nothing and can be omitted.

```
subFolder.GetFiles().Where(Function(m) (m.Attributes And FileAttributes.Hidden) = 0).Count
```